# How to implement dangling-pointer warning in custom string type

Tags: c++, lifetime, cpp-core-guidelines

The following code is invalid because it takes a pointer into a temporary object (triggering `-Wdangling-gsl`):

```
static std::string f() {
    return "hi";
}

void func() {
    const char* ptr = f().c_str();
}
```

```
<source>:8:23: warning: object backing the pointer will be destroyed at the end of the full-expression [-Wdangling-gsl]
```

I have a custom string class which looks and feels a lot like `std::string`, but internally represents the text in a different way.

Is there a way to make `MyString::c_str` also generate a similar warning if used in this way?

Comment: Interesting question. I'd take a peek a your `<string>` header file and see what you see,

Comment: This question is compiler specific (as much as I know C++ language does not support this), so it would be helpful to specify which one you are using.

Comment: Ideally it'd be universal but we definitely focus on Clang.

Comment: For it to be universal it has to be supported on the language level, and it is obviously not supported.

Comment: There's nothing that stands out in libc++.

`_LIBCPP_HIDE_FROM_ABI _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_SINCE_CXX20 const value_type* c_str() const _NOEXCEPT {return data();}`

I checked the call chain and there didn't seem to be any special attributes for this.

Comment: Well you could always return a raii object that behaves like a `char*` (an object with implicit conversion operator char*(), the one time implicit conversion actually is useful IMO). And then document your c_str() returned value is only valid for the current scope. There is no need to have dangling pointers at all.

Comment: Pepjin, this approach wouldn't work with printf.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so for **warning** (unless compiler has extension for that), but you can forbid that function on temporary (which would forbid also valid usage).

```
const char* MyString::c_str() const && = delete;
```

Comment: This would forbid valid usage as well, like `printf("%s", foo().c_str())`

Comment: @StilesCrisis +1 - https://ideone.com/IRtALB

Comment: @StilesCrisis: I agree. C++, contrary to Rust doesn't have lifetime within the type to spot dangling pointer.